# Owl Carousel Item Background Color

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) and I am trying to get a background color for each item individually, but everything I tried does not work and the background remains transparent.

```
<div class="row" id="carousel4" class="owl-carousel" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; margin-top: 15px; padding-left: 30px;">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid #ff00ff; padding: 0px;">
            <div style="background-color: #ccc;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">MAR</span></div>
            <div style="background-color: #fff;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">12</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">DAY + NIGHT</span><br /><span style="font-size: 18px;">"Event Title"</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><img src="/img/view-deals-sm.png" style="max-width: 100%;" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><img src="/img/free-limo-sm.png" style="max-width: 100%;" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid #ff00ff; padding: 0px;">
            <div style="background-color: #ccc;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">MAR</span></div>
            <div style="background-color: #fff;"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">12</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9"><span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">DAY + NIGHT</span><br /><span style="font-size: 18px;">"Event Title"</span></div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><img src="/img/view-deals-sm.png" style="max-width: 100%;" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><img src="/img/free-limo-sm.png" style="max-width: 100%;" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried that I thought should work:

```
#carousel4 .item {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Well now... It appears to be working in the fiddle but not in my full site: http://jsfiddle.net/853uhv8o/

Comment: this is not recommended, but if you really need it you could do this `background-color: #fff !important;`